# Unresolved reference to WixUI:WixUI_InstallDir

Tags: dll, command-line, wix, wix3.7

i am using wix from command line. the problem i am facing is that i don't know how i will load the WixUtilExtension.dll at link time.

currently i am using the following commands

```
candle install.wxs
```

and then

```
light -ext WixUtilExtension install.wixobj
```

but it gives me following error

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_InstallDir in section product
```

the dll is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin` and my files are in folder which is at Desktop
can some body help me in resolving this?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are linking `WixUtilExtension`, but the `WixUI_InstallDir` is a part of `WixUIExtension`. Seems like a pure typo.